# How save styles in less variables?

Tags: css, less

I have a doub in less (sorry am very novice).
the next code can be posible? I mean, exist a way to do something like this?

```
@var01: {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}


.my_style {
  @var01;
  color: red;
}
```

I want save a class into a varible, and later use it.
is posible? 
thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

The feature you are looking for is [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature):

```
.foo {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}


.my_style {
  .foo();
  color: red;
}
```